# How do I bypass a single phase bridge rectifier?

Tags: ac, dc, rectifier

I have a PCB that has a 16V AC input and is rectified into 12V DC by [a BR102 rectifier.](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/258/BR1005_THRU_BR1010-2510434.pdf)

If I were to wire the output of this to 12V DC from a lead acid battery, would it have any detrimental effects to the component by voltage 'feeding' through the wrong way?

There would be no load on the AC side, this would be disconnected when the 12V DC is in use.

Comment: I have doubts about what you think is the AC level and what you think is the DC level. So, please provide a schematic of the design.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a schematic as it is an off the shelf piece of kit. 
It takes 230V AC or 110V AC into the primary side of a step down transformer. This outputs 16V AC on the secondary side.
The 16V AC goes into the BR102 Single Phase Bridge Rectifier and is rectified down to 12V DC which is then used to power the rest of the PCB from there

Comment: A rectifier can’t rectify ‘down’ from 16VAC to 12VDC, it would yield 22V or so at peak and would require some additional regulation beyond that so it would pay to investigate a little further and see how/where this is done.  If there’s a linear regulator e.g. 7812 then you would need to switch between this and the battery supply.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you’d face is not reverse leakage through the rectifier - this would happen but at a very low level, 10uA at room temperature, so probably well below what your circuit consumes.  The problem would arise if you had both the battery and AC power present together, as the 16VAC supply would charge the 12V battery, with nothing to limit the current.

I might guess that your circuit regulates 16VAC down to 12V, so supplying it with 12VDC would be below the dropout voltage of the regulator so the post-regulator voltage would be below 12V, which is undesirable.  However without details of the rest of the circuit it’s impossible to say.

Comment: Thanks, all noted. The AC power and 12v Battery would never be present together which helps things. Thank you for the comments about post regulator voltage, I'll see what I can reverse engineer from the PCB and figure out where any issues might lye.

Answer (score 0):

A selector switch may be used to keep the power supply and the battery isolated.

[image]